# compare only less indexed records than the current index in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to get the duplicate values of a column to show the error message in another column of the `datatable` that `Duplicate Values Not Allowed`

For that I am grouping the `datatable` columns and checking duplicates exists or not like below

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(r => checkValidation(r, i++));
    private void checkValidation(DataRow Row, int RowId)
    {           
      if ((dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().GroupBy(r => r[colName]).SelectMany(dup => dup.Skip(1))).Count() > 0)
      {
          Row["Error List"] += "Duplicate Values Not Allowed";
      }
    }
```

here the problem is it will give the error message for all the rows that has duplicates values as below

```
Name         Error List
----------   ----------
Test Upload  Duplicate Values Not Allowed
Test Upload  Duplicate Values Not Allowed
```

but what I want is

```
Name         Error List
----------   ----------
Test Upload  
Test Upload  Duplicate Values Not Allowed
```

To get it we can only compare the less indexed rows than the current index. But how to do the same using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking for *any* duplicates and then marking the current row as a duplicate.  The row `Row` is not used anywhere in your validation check other than to assign the error.

Should this work, you'd be doing the same validation *n* times, where *n* is the number of rows.  Why not approach this differently and do the validation in one go?

You can get all duplicate groups like this:

```
var duplicateGroups = dt.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => r["Name"])
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

And then set an error for all duplicates except the first:

```
foreach (var row in duplicateGroups.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)))
{
    row["Error List"] += "Duplicate Values Not Allowed";
}
```

With my test data, I get this output:

```
Name            Error List
--------------------------------------------
Test Upload
Test Upload     Duplicate Values Not Allowed
Test Upload     Duplicate Values Not Allowed
Test Upload 2
Test Upload 2   Duplicate Values Not Allowed
Test Upload 3
```

Comment: `dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(r => r["Name"]).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))` you mean this?

Comment: If you're going to write it in one line then you could skip the `Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` as the `Skip(1)` effectively does the same thing.

Comment: I am iterating through the datatable and writing on the error list column that this is duplicate. see the edited question.

Comment: As I explain in the answer, even if you made this work it is very inefficient as you are doing the same check *n* times.  The method I suggested only does the check once and achieves the same outcome.